# Buffer to string difference in NodeJs Vs Python

Tags: python, node.js, encoding, binary, buffer

I have an incoming buffer whose print to terminal differs between node and python, although both show the same length of 62

1) Python print(in_buffer)
    b'\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x03\x00\x00user\x00postgres\x00database\x00postgres\x00extra_float_digits\x002\x00\x00'

vs

Node console.log(in_buffer.toString()))

userpostgresdatabasepostgresextra_float_digits2

Is there a way to print same output in node (looks like it has something to do with null termination)

Comment: You just don't see the low bytes in Node because you are printing it as a string. Just don't convert it with `.toString()`. Other than that, JS is going to print the actual characters and you'll lose most of it. There's no nice way of displaying it in JS, you could try with `JSON.stringify(in_buffer.toString())`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli:- Thanks